# Divs w/ Inline onClick Usability

Tags: javascript, html, performance, onclick, inline

I was working on a side project and decided not to use jQuery for it so all my scripts are in vanilla.

I came across a part where I have several buttons to select a size for a t-shirt as below:

```
<div class="row animated" id="step3">
    <div class="step-heading" id="t-shirt-size">
        <h3>Select your T-Shirt Size</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-s-6">
        <div class="main-div ts left" id="xs" >XS</div>
        <div class="main-div ts left" id="m" >M</div>
        <div class="main-div ts left" id="xl" >XL</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-s-6">
        <div class="main-div ts right" id="s" >S</div>
        <div class="main-div ts right" id="l" >L</div>
        <div class="main-div ts right" id="xxl" >XXL</div>
    </div>
</div><!--end step tshirt size-->
```

I was using this script to check if the button is clicked and assign it to a value in a key:value array.

```
var shirtSizeSizes = document.getElementsByClassName('ts');
for (var i = 0; i < shirtSizeSizes.length; i++) {
    shirtSizeSizes[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        checkTSValueButtonClicked(this);
    });
}

function checkTSValueButtonClicked(el) {
    //values has a key for shirtSize
    values.shirtSize = el.getAttribute('data-value')
}
```

The reasoning behind using the loop is that there is no other way to add a click listener onto each of them. It would still involve click listeners for X buttons/divs.

Now I had several of these blocks for multiple things (such as pants size and etc) and as you can tell the looping would not only be repetitive but also have an impact on performance (even if minimal).

So my question is: Is this the only time (in terms of best practices and all that stuff) to use something like

```
<div class="main-div ts right" id="xxl" onclick="checkTSValueButtonClicked(this)">XXL</div>
```

so that

1. I don't need to loop through multiple times for different size divs
2. I can clean up the code a bit and leave only the second function to use

If I am totally forgetting an easy way to do this, it's totally because I have sat behind a computer for multiple hours and my brain is a bit fried; so any help in terms of code readability and performance would be appreciated.

Thanks for your time :)

Edit:

Thanks for the answers. Anyone also looking into this topic, I found this post useful : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the normal input controls i.e. radio buttons for this?

Comment: no specific reason , just didn't come to mind @jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First solution** - loop

This would be the best--not a performance hit at all.

**Second solution** - event handler on a parent

You can set an event handler on some parent element and check if the right element was clicked:

```
var parent=document.getElementsById('step3');
parent.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var x = e.target;

    if (x.classList.contains('ts')) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

**Third solution** - inline event handlers

```
 <div class="main-div ts right"id="xxl" onclick="checkTSValueButtonClicked(this)">XXL</div>
```

Aside from bad practice, your `checkTSValue...` function must be in the global scope in order to be accessible, so if it is wrapped in the `window.onload` it won't work.

Comment: 1) There would not be a performance hit even if say looping through like 500+ buttons or something? Obviously that is not the case here but I am just wondering. 2) That would work 3) Good catch.... Thanks for your response

Comment: 500+ maybe would be, but wrapped into `window.onload,` handlers will be added(not executed),after content get rendered not affecting user exp.